# How do I create for each value inside of multi-dimensional array, a function named after value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
      $realThing= array(
[foo] => Array
        (
            [id] => foo
            [tag] => {my:foo}
            [label] => Foo
            [callback] => foo
        )

    [surveyid] => Array
        (
            [id] => surveyid
            [tag] => {my:surveyid}
            [label] => Surveyid
            [callback] => surveyid
        )

    [membername] => Array
        (
            [id] => membername
            [tag] => {my:membername}
            [label] => Membername
            [callback] => membername
        )
```

I am trying to create a function for each value in 'callback' key.

For example:

```
function foo(){}
function surveyid(){}
function membername(){}
```

attempt:

```
foreach($realThing[$key] as $key => $value){
         function $realThing[$key]['callback'](){
             return '$otherArray[$Key]';
         }}
```

all help appreciated...

Comment: It would help if you told me what you were trying to accomplish with this. I think your approach is probably somewhat misguided but it's hard to say for sure unless I know what the end goal is. Also, please re-phrase your post as an actual question.

Comment: I concur, I'm having some trouble figuring out what you're trying to do. Anyway, you can't created named functions on the fly, but you can create anonymous functions; e.g: `$foo = function () { /* function contents */ };` if that's helpful

Comment: @Difster I am trying to get this working [http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/merge-tags/]

Comment: Lots of keys in that short snippet of code. I would not be able to keep track of  them all, you must be a janitor to keep track of them.

Comment: @user3147682 - That link doesn't work. Try again.

Comment: http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/merge-tags/

Comment: @Difster http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/merge-tags/

Comment: Ok, so what's not working?

Comment: @Difster syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `array_map()` (http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php):

```
foreach($realThing[$key] as $key => $value){
    array_map($realThing[$key]['callback'], $otherValue);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an anonymous function inside of your loop:

```
foreach($realThing[$key] as $key => $value){
     function ($realThing[$key]['callback']){
         return '$otherArray[$key]';
     }
}
```

Note: I can't guarantee that will work because I'm not certain it's what you're trying to accomplish, but from a workability standpoint, it's correct. Also notice that I corrected the capitalization of `$Key` to `$key` in the `return` line.